# ThreeJS: Transparent Background with Bokeh Shader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I applied a bokeh / depth of field on my canvas. Works fine, but for future needs I will need to add a background with CSS. That's why I need it transparent.

I used the code from this example:
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_dof.html

Here is how it looks right now:
http://normanwink.com/demo/bokeh/
You will notice a black background, but the body is set to dark gray; Klick the "Add"-button on the bottom right.

I created a Codepen to provide easier access to the code.
Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to run.
Still: https://codepen.io/normanwink/pen/gGvQgo

I had a look into the RenderPass.js

```
THREE.RenderPass = function ( scene, camera, overrideMaterial, clearColor, clearAlpha ) {

    THREE.Pass.call( this );

    this.scene = scene;
    this.camera = camera;

    this.overrideMaterial = overrideMaterial;

    this.clearColor = clearColor;
    this.clearAlpha = ( clearAlpha !== undefined ) ? clearAlpha : 0;

    this.clear = true;
    this.clearDepth = false;
    this.needsSwap = false;

};
```

This looks promising, but I don't know exactly what to do.

- ThreeJS r87

Thanks!

Comment: i have the same problem, did you find an answer?